# Generated 2 tables based on 2 separate javascript arrays

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

I am trying to build out 2 html tables from 2 different JavaScript data arrays.

The first table builds out fine and structure looks great but the second table doesn't populate data.

I tried adjusting the naming but I think since it's looking for "tbody" both times.

Is there another variable to adjust this or perhaps a better way to have 2 separate tables from 2 different data arrays?

I swapped the naming and added ID tags to the tbody with no change in results. I was going to just rename the data tables but seems like the construction of the second table grabbing tbody is just adjusting the first tbody.

```
<div style="float: left;margin-right:10px">
    <table>
       <thead>
        <tr align="center">
            <th><h3>Name</h3></th>
            <th><h3>Time</h3></th>
            <th><h3>Temp</h3></th>
            <th><h3>Peel</h3></th>
        </tr>
       </thead>
       <tbody id="tbody"></tbody>
    </table>
</div>

<script>
const data = [  
        {name: "Apple", time: "25sec", temp: "100F", peel: "Peeler"},
        {name: "Orange", time: "50sec", temp: "200F", peel: "Knife"},
        ]

    const table = document.querySelector('tbody')

    data.forEach((item) => {
        table.insertAdjacentHTML( 'beforeend', `<tr>
                <td>${item.name}</td>
        <td>${item.time}</td>
                <td>${item.temp} </td>
                <td>${item.peel}</td>

            </tr>`)
    })

</script>



<div style="float: left">
    <table>
       <thead>
        <tr align="center">
            <th><h3>Name</h3></th>
            <th><h3>Time</h3></th>
            <th><h3>Temp</h3></th>
            <th><h3>Peel</h3></th>
        </tr>
       </thead>
       <tbody></tbody>
    </table>
</div>

<script>


<script>
const data = [  
        {name: "Apple", time: "25sec", temp: "100F", peel: "Peeler"},
        {name: "Orange", time: "50sec", temp: "200F", peel: "Knife"},
        ]


    const table = document.querySelector('tbody')

    data.forEach((item) => {
        table.insertAdjacentHTML( 'beforeend', `<tr>
                <td>${item.name}</td>
                <td>${item.time}</td>
                <td>${item.temp}</td>
                <td>${item.peel}</td>
            </tr>`)
    })

</script>
```

Comment: It may be trendy to omit the subjects from your sentences, but it makes you more difficult to understand.

Comment: you can't use the same variable names in both parts of the script. Use different names. E.g. `data1` and `table1` for the first table, `data2` and `table2` for the second one.

Comment: Create a function, for example `generateTable(data)`. Then, inside that function, loop through your `data` argument / array of objects, picking up the keys. Use them for `th` text. Use the values for `td`. Finally, append your newly created table to the DOM. This suggestion assumes that the elements of your collection will have the same structure / same keys.

Comment: Also, the selector `tbody` will just select the body of the first table. You need a selector that distinguishes the tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider extracting the row creation into a function and giving the two tbody elements unique ids to distinguish them.

```js
function addRows(tbody, data) {
    data.forEach((item) => {
        tbody.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', `<tr>
                <td>${item.name}</td>
        <td>${item.time}</td>
                <td>${item.temp} </td>
                <td>${item.peel}</td>

            </tr>`)
    });
}
const data1=[{name:"Apple",time:"25sec",temp:"100F",peel:"Peeler"},{name:"Orange",time:"50sec",temp:"200F",peel:"Knife"},];
const tbody1 = document.querySelector('#tbody1');
addRows(tbody1, data1);
const data2=[{name:"Apple",time:"25sec",temp:"100F",peel:"Peeler"},{name:"Orange",time:"50sec",temp:"200F",peel:"Knife"},];
const tbody2 = document.querySelector('#tbody2');
addRows(tbody2, data2);
```

```html
<div style="float: left;margin-right:10px">
    <table>
       <thead>
        <tr align="center">
            <th><h3>Name</h3></th>
            <th><h3>Time</h3></th>
            <th><h3>Temp</h3></th>
            <th><h3>Peel</h3></th>
        </tr>
       </thead>
       <tbody id="tbody1"></tbody>
    </table>
</div>
<div style="float: left">
    <table>
       <thead>
        <tr align="center">
            <th><h3>Name</h3></th>
            <th><h3>Time</h3></th>
            <th><h3>Temp</h3></th>
            <th><h3>Peel</h3></th>
        </tr>
       </thead>
       <tbody id="tbody2"></tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few issues with your code.
You are declaring `data` and `table` as constants in the first `<script>` tag, and then you try to reassing their values in the second `<script>` tag. (constant variables cannot be reassigned).
In addition, `document.querySelector('tbody')` will always select the very first `<tbody>` element that is found on the page. This would cause to select the same table twice.

```html
<div style="float: left;margin-right:10px">
    <table>
       <thead>
        <tr align="center">
            <th><h3>Name</h3></th>
            <th><h3>Time</h3></th>
            <th><h3>Temp</h3></th>
            <th><h3>Peel</h3></th>
        </tr>
       </thead>
       <tbody id="table-1"></tbody>
    </table>
</div>

<div style="float: left">
    <table>
       <thead>
        <tr align="center">
            <th><h3>Name</h3></th>
            <th><h3>Time</h3></th>
            <th><h3>Temp</h3></th>
            <th><h3>Peel</h3></th>
        </tr>
       </thead>
       <tbody id="table-2"></tbody>
    </table>
</div>

<script>

    // Array containing data
    let data = [  
        {name: "Apple", time: "25sec", temp: "100F", peel: "Peeler"},
        {name: "Orange", time: "50sec", temp: "200F", peel: "Knife"},
    ];

    // The tbodies have different IDs
    let table_1 = document.querySelector('#table-1');
    let table_2 = document.querySelector('#table-2');


    // Object [] notation 
    table_1.insertAdjacentHTML( 'beforeend', 
        `
            <tr>
                <td>${data[0]['name']}</td>
                <td>${data[0]['time']}</td>
                <td>${data[0]['temp']}</td>
                <td>${data[0]['peel']}</td>    
            </tr>
        `
    );

    table_2.insertAdjacentHTML( 'beforeend', 
        `
            <tr>
                <td>${data[1]['name']}</td>
                <td>${data[1]['time']}</td>
                <td>${data[1]['temp']}</td>
                <td>${data[1]['peel']}</td>    
            </tr>
        `
    );
</script>
```

This is how I would refactor this code, but there are endless ways to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

You can't give to a tbody element a id like "tbody" and left the other without id.
By doing this you are selecting twice the same tbody tag (the first), regardless of their IDs.
So use two different id like "tb1" and "tb2".

For the remnant things you can refer to @Unmitigated answer that beat me in time and is the best. ^_^